# Crystal lang : method_missing for class object?

Tags: crystal-lang, method-missing

Something like this?

```
class A
    module ClassMethods
        macro method_missing(call)
            {% p call %}
        end
    end
    extend ClassMethods
end
A.a
```

Result of the code is `Error : undefined method 'a' for A:Class`. It seems `method_missing` doesn't work for class object.

The reason for the question is that I implemented a class with a `current` class method to get an instance for current context. For the simplification, I want some like [`forward_missing_to`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.25.1/Object.html#forward_missing_to(delegate)-macro) to replace `MyClass.current.xxx` with `MyClass.xxx`, so `method_missing` is required according `forward_missing_to`'s implementation.

I also found, [`delegate`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.25.1/Object.html#delegate%28%2Amethods%2Ctoobject%29-macro) works fine for class methods using above way. So actually my pratical problem has been solved, but I'm still interesting with the question : `method_missing` for class object, is it impossible?

Comment: There's no way to do this right now. Also, `method_missing` is discouraged and I can imagine it being removed in the future.